# Get list of products from wordpress table using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, wordpress

I'm working on a Laravel project where I need to retrieve products from a WordPress database based on a specific attribute value. The attribute in question is "brand," and I'm trying to fetch products where the brand is "7M." I'm using Laravel Eloquent and have set up models for Product and PostMeta to interact with the WordPress tables.

```
class Product extends Model{
public function meta()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PostMeta', 'post_id');
}}

class PostMeta extends Model{
public function scopeMetaKey($query, $key)
{
    return $query->where('meta_key', $key);
}

public function scopeMetaValue($query, $value)
{
    return $query->where('meta_value', $value);
}
```

}

```
$brandName = '7M';
$metaKey = 'pa_brand'; // Replace with the actual meta key for the brand attribute

$product = Product::whereHas('meta', function ($query) use ($brandName, $metaKey) {
    $query->metaKey($metaKey)->metaValue($brandName);
})->first();
```

this is the solution suggested by chatgpt, coz I am not an expert of WordPress tables.

when I execute this query it returns me null, but I have a product whose attribute has brand =7M.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can debug this by examining the actual SQL query sent to the database.

```
\DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable the query log

// Your Eloquent queries

dd(\DB::getQueryLog()); // Display the query logs
```

Hope this helps.